# How can I solve this weird collider bug in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am new to Unity and I am working on a 2d game. Here I only have a background, a boat and an island. The problem is that the boat should not go under the island.

I did a little bit of research and I found out that I should have colliders so know my boat has a box collider 2d and a rigidbody 2d and my island a polygon collider 2d. The problem with this is that whenever I try to go through the island, the boat gets in a weird angle.

EDIT: Sorry there is no video for now but here is a full sequence: 
[image]

This is the script for my boats movement if you need it:

```
public float moveSpeed;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool playerMovement;
    private Vector2 lastMove;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    } 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        playerMovement = false;
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f) {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f));
            playerMovement = true;
            lastMove = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f);
        }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
            playerMovement = true;
            lastMove = new Vector2(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        }
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        anim.SetFloat("MoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        anim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", playerMovement);
        anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", lastMove.x);
        anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", lastMove.y);
    }
```

Animator - [image]

Comment: OK you could make your boat not a box but boat shaped collider, and then on contact with island make it stop moving.

Comment: Can you attach an screenshot of your animator and a video of this happening? You can use CloudApp for the video or gif

Comment: @bugFinder thanks for the answer. I will try this and yes I can upload the animator

Comment: @MauricioEstevez could you add images and gifs directly to the question using the according formatting tools here on StackOverflow?

Comment: @derHugo sorry there is no video but if you click in the image you can see a full sequence of the problem. My boat moves up and down correctly but when it hits the island, it goes under the island and the move in a wierd angle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting strange behavior because you are trying to control your object both with animation and physics. Whenever you hit a collider physics simulation is interrupted by the animator. You can try to change the `Rigidbody2D` `BodyType` to `Kinematic`:

[image]

Anyway as long as your boat animation/movement is that simple it it better to control movement with physics not animator. Use animator for animations like ship exploding, sinking etc. and control your ship position with physics or transform.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `sortingLayerName` to what you want.

```
myCanvasObject.GetComponent(Canvas).sortingLayerName="mySortingLayer";
```

you can also do it in the unity editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to the physics to apply, you should use the `Rigidbody2D` instead of the `Transform`.

Instead of using `transform.Translate()` to move the ship, use the [Rigidbody2D.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) instead.

At the start you can get the `Rigidbody2D` like you are getting the `Animator` by doing:

```cs
rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

Then you can set it's velocity depending on the input:

```cs
rb.velocity = new Vector2(
    Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed,
    Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed);
```

Also, make sure that the rigidbody is **not** set to Kinematic (unlike what a previous answer suggested).

Comment: 1. I suggested to use Kinematic in case he needs to move the Rigidbody2D non-physically [as Unity suggest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic.html). 2. I have recommended him to use physics or transform instead.